# Definition of Hermitian linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

1.Given a matrix A, what does $\overline A^t$ mean? I guess it is first taking conjugate for each entry in A and then taking transpose. Or is there anything to do with "Hermitian"?
For example, if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1+i & 1-i\\2+i & 2-i\\\end{bmatrix} $$ what does $\overline A^t$ look like?

2.Also, I am wondering what is the definition of "a linear transformation is Hermitian"? Does it mean its corresponding matrix is Hermitian?

Comment: 1. Yep, conjugate and transpose (or transpose and then conjugate). Often denoted as $A^*$.

2. Yes again.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of Hermitian linear transformations requires your complex vector space to have an additional structure, a Hermitian product, i.e. a conjugated-symmetric inner product: $x\cdot y = (y\cdot x)^*$, with $^*$ denoting complex cojugation. A linear operator $A$ is then called Hermitian if $x\cdot Ay =(y\cdot Ax)^*$. The matrix of a Hermitian operator is a Hermitian matrix (in the sense that the matrix is equal to its transpose complex conjugate) IF the matrix is written in an orthonormal basis (for a general basis the matrix of a Hermitian operator is NOT in general a Hermitian matrix).